# Dapper.net with unknown quantity of array elements

Tags: arrays, dapper

What I'm trying to do it have a filter object that is populated like so

```
var filter = new Filter
{
    ThingID = 1,
    Keywords = new[] { "op", "s" }
};
```

And then be able to build up the query like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("select * from Stuff where 1=1");
if (filter.ThingID.HasValue)
{
    sb.AppendLine(" and ThingID = @ThingID");
}
if (filter.Keywords != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < filter.Keywords.Length; i++)
    {
        string keyword = filter.Keywords[i];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(" and ( Model like '%' || @Keywords" + i + " || '%' )");
        }
    }
}
var sql = sb.ToString();
var results = Query<Stuff>(sql, filter).ToList();
```

This works fine if just the ThingID prop is populated, but as far as I can tell Dapper is not feeding the Keywords in as a parameter in any way. Is this possible with Dapper, or does it only work in the context of " where Keywords in @Keywords"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters need to match by name; you are adding parameters like `@Keywords17`, but there is no `Keywords17` property for it to add. It doesn't interpret that as `Keywords[17]`, if that is what you mean. There *is* some automatic expansion of flat arrays, but that is intended for expanding `in @Keywords` (although the expansion itself is not specific to `in`). There is not currently something that would help you automatically there; I would suggest `DynamicPaameters` instead:

```
var args = new DynamicParameters();
args.Add("ThingID", 1);
...
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
{
    sb.AppendLine(" and ( Model like '%' || @Keywords" + i + " || '%' )");
    args.Add("Keywords" + i, keyword);
}
...
var cmd = new CommandDefinition(sql, args, flags: CommandFlags.NoCache);
var results = Query<Stuff>(cmd).AsList();
```

note the subtle two changes at the end here - `CommandFlags.NoCache` will help avoid building lots of lookup entries for similar but different SQL (although you might choose to pay this to reduce per-item cost, up to you). The `AsList` instead of `ToList` avoids an extra list allocation.